# Emacs make ibuffer filter per frame

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `ibuffer` as well as have opened several frames. The very frequent use-case of mine for `ibuffer` is to filter the list (`C-x C-b`) of buffers by name/filename. The catch is that filter works in the same way for all frame (it is predicted I believe). I'd want to have to apply filter for ibuffer listing per each frame I have.

E.g. in a first frame I'd like to see list of buffers filtered by a filename, in a second one filtered by mode.

Looking around `ibuffer.el` I have discovered an entity called `ibuffer-filtering-qualifiers` which holds an associative list of currently applied filters. I have tried played:

```
(let ((ibuffer-filtering-qualifiers '())) ;;; Imitate that there are no filters applied
   (call-interactively 'ibuffer))
```

But this was not worked for me.

Could you please point me out how to achieve such desired behavior of `ibuffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `ibuffer-update` uses the `buffer-list`, which includes all frames.  Modifying `ibuffer-update` from using `buffer-list` to `(frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'buffer-list)` approaches the behavior you are seeking.  An ibuffer filter based upon that same concept should also be possible.

In my opinion, the per frame buffer list `(frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'buffer-list)` is not the best method to associate buffers with frames because it gets modified too easily.  The best method I have seen is frame-bufs by Al Parker:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs  This has been updated to work with a current version of Emacs, however, I am using a slightly modified version to suit my own needs.

So, the easiest method that I am aware to answer your question is to use a combination of frame-bufs by Al Parker, and use the `frame-bufs-buffer-list` within `ibuffer-update`.  That gives you the best of both worlds.  Here is an example that will give you a nice ibuffer with only the buffers associated with a given frame -- all other buffers will not be displayed.  [FYI:  frame-bufs also sorts by mode or by file name.]

```
(require 'ibuffer)

(defalias 'ibuffer-update 'lawlist-ibuffer-update)

(defun lawlist-ibuffer-update (arg &optional silent)
  "Regenerate the list of all buffers.

Prefix arg non-nil means to toggle whether buffers that match
`ibuffer-maybe-show-predicates' should be displayed.

If optional arg SILENT is non-nil, do not display progress messages."
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (setq ibuffer-display-maybe-show-predicates
        (not ibuffer-display-maybe-show-predicates)))
  (ibuffer-forward-line 0)
  ;; (let* ((bufs (buffer-list))
  (let* ((bufs (frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'frame-bufs-buffer-list))
     (blist (ibuffer-filter-buffers
         (current-buffer)
         (if (and
              (cadr bufs)
              (eq ibuffer-always-show-last-buffer
              :nomini)
              (minibufferp (cadr bufs)))
             (cl-caddr bufs)
           (cadr bufs))
         (ibuffer-current-buffers-with-marks bufs)
         ibuffer-display-maybe-show-predicates)))
    (and (null blist)
     (featurep 'ibuf-ext)
     ibuffer-filtering-qualifiers
     (message "No buffers! (note: filtering in effect)"))
    (unless silent
      (message "Updating buffer list..."))
    (ibuffer-redisplay-engine blist arg)
    (unless silent
      (message "Updating buffer list...done")))
  (if (eq ibuffer-shrink-to-minimum-size 'onewindow)
      (ibuffer-shrink-to-fit t)
    (when ibuffer-shrink-to-minimum-size
      (ibuffer-shrink-to-fit)))
  (ibuffer-forward-line 0)
  ;; I tried to update this automatically from the mode-line-process format,
  ;; but changing nil-ness of header-line-format while computing
  ;; mode-line-format is asking a bit too much it seems.  --Stef
  (setq header-line-format
        (and ibuffer-use-header-line
             ibuffer-filtering-qualifiers
             ibuffer-header-line-format)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is not that the ibuffer works in the same way for all frames.  The issue is that the ibuffer buffer is the **same** for all the frames (each frame has a separate window (with its cursor) showing your ibuffer unique instance).

A simple solution is to clone the ibuffer buffer (M-x clone-buffer). And that is: you have two different buffers and you can apply filters to them independently.